# links to another website without my own url

Tags: field, link

If I want to link another website, I am doing this with a normal text field.

```
<a href="{{ entry.subHeading }}" target="_blank">{{ entry.subHeading }}</a>
```

***subHeading*** is the link.

If I now click on the text on my website, I get something like this: `www.example.com/https://www.google.ch`

How can I get my own website text out of the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `subHeading` is a `plain text` field. 
Just a guess, are you inserting a string that can be interpreted as a relative path on your website?

Ex. `google.com` vs `https://www.google.com`

The first will lead to yoursite.com/google.com, the latter should work fine.